# Passing variable value from js file to hbs component

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

Hi I have a Global variable as in js file, I want to retrieve value of that Variable in hbs file

```
    export default () => {
    selectedViolationTypeId: 0,
    addProgram(program) {
         this.set('selectedViolationTypeId', program.ViolationTypeId);
     },
    }
```

The value of the selectedViolationTypeId changes in the addProgram function call, that changed value I want to retrieve in the hbs file, at the URL field like this:
url='api/branch/inspectionitemcategories/dt?violationTypeId={selectedViolationTypeId}'

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
                    {{log 'selectedViolationTypeId'}}
                    {{log selectedViolationTypeId}}
                        <div class="form-group chosen-fix {{if failTest 'has-error q'}}">
                            <label class="control-label">Inspection Item Categories</label>
                            {{#drop-down url='api/branch/inspectionitemcategories/dt?violationTypeId={selectedViolationTypeId}'
                            id='idInspectionItemCategories'
                            required=false
                            placeholder='Add Program (Search)'
                            showSelected=false f=f as |item|
                            }}
                            {{log 'item 1'}}
                            {{log item}}
                            {{#if item}}
                            {{partial 'components/edit-item/partial-select1'}}
                            {{else}}
                            <i>Nothing Here</i>
                            {{/if}}
                            {{/drop-down}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But its not happening, at the url field  this selected value is coming as null with error message as below

```
:56974/api/branch/inspectionitemcategories/dt?violationTypeId={{this.selectedViolationTypeId}}:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
api.js:77 api/branch/inspectionitemcategories/dt?violationTypeId={{this.selectedViolationTypeId}} error undefined Object
```

can somebody please help me how can I retrieve its value in the front end hbs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make global variable value visible in the hbs template by defining a property in the component / controller. So, in your component code, define a getter:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  get violationTypeId() {
    return selectedViolationTypeId;
  }
}
```

And now you can use it in template:

```
{{log this.violationTypeId}}
```

P. S. You could use this global variable via a service. Either add it to an existing service, if the value belongs there logically, or create a new service:

```js
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class MyService extends Service {
  @tracked selectedViolationTypeId = DEFAULT_VALUE;

  @action addProgram(program) {
    this.selectedViolationTypeId = program?.ViolationTypeId;
  }
}
```

Then, you can inject this service into your component / controller:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @service myService;
}
```

And use the value in template:

```
{{log this.myService.selectedViolationTypeId}}
```

Comment: If I don't have a class for this component but it has export default function, and if I am setting this value in an another function like , saveProgram(program) {   this.set('selectedViolationTypeId', program.ViolationTypeId);}, then how can I retrieve it? This value changes in saveProgram function, then how can I do it?

Comment: This in entirely different question from what you asked originally. I would suggest adhering the official "data down, actions up" paradigm. If you need this value accessible globally in your app, another option is to consider making it accessible as a property of some service.

Comment: But how? can you please give some example my friend

Comment: My friend, I have updated my answer. I am not sure if this is helpful, but I hope it is.

Comment: Sure thank you, we are close, now I want only small change, can we have this addProgram function in the controller, controller passes a value to a function in the Service and Service changes the Value which we try to access in the hbs, because addProgram does some stuff that we may not do it in the Service - any help thank you so much for all the help my friend

Comment: I am sure you will be able to easily implement that functionality yourself :)